# Protractor File Upload using button

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

Can someone post an example of how to upload a file in protractor using a button? Not sure if setFileDetector is needed in here or not.

I am using Protractor, JS, selenium standalone server, and have a button to select a file, i.e.

Button: Select File

```
button id="upload-button" class="button" ng-file-select ng-file-change="uploadCtrl.upload($files)" ng-accept="'*.jpg, *.gif'"
```

Can someone explain how to upload the file in protractor? Thanks!!

Comment: Explore the HTML source code - there should be an `input` field with `type="file"`. It can be hidden. Provide the HTML code of the input if you'll find it. Thanks.

Comment: As @alecxe said look for the `type="file"` `input` field in the HTML code. It should be one level up of the button ideally.